# Can you make a Windows network default user profile NOT apply to a certain operating system?

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-profile

I would like to create a network Default User account for Windows 7 *only*.

This is on a Windows 2003 domain with servers from Windows 2000 to 2008 R2 and Windows XP on workstation side. We're about to do a full migration to Windows 7 and I'd like to start using the network default user profile functionality as we're not migrating user profiles over. Want everyone to start clean.

I followed the simple steps from this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973289 under the heading: **"How to turn the default user profile into a network default user profile in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2"** but the problem is that profile would then apply to a new user\admin logging into a 2008 *server*. That's no good. Anyone have any ideas on how to limit what actually uses that network profile? I was thinking about setting deny permissions for all my admin\service accounts on that "\\dcserver\netlogon\Default User.v2" folder but then it might be timing out and cause other problems. Haven't tried yet as that seems like a bad way of making this work.

Comment: What users log on to servers? Administrators? If so, I wouldn't recommend enabling roaming profiles for those accounts anyway. The last thing you want is complications arising from profiles not loading when you need to fix something fast on critical servers.

Comment: this does not have anything to do with roaming profiles. this is only regarding a default profile (what is used to create a profile the first time you logon to a machine). You know the Default Profile that you have on local computers? It's that, only stored on the network, so if you want\need to make a change to the Default profile across the domain easily, you can. It's a nice feature, if they let you have separate ones for workstations vs servers. again, this is NOT a roaming profile issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with Microsoft Support, no, this cannot be done but you can apply the profile to only be accessed by certain groups. Good enough for now - sort of. But if my server Admins wanted to use this feature, it's either one or the other - you can't have one for each OS.